# Faster 32 bit execution with Hyperthreading disabled?

Tags: cpu, 32-bit, threads

I am using numpy-Python scripts that take a lot of computing power to execute. The scripts themselves are already quite well written an I can say that I cannot really improve their speed by writing them better.

I have an intel i7 m620 (old guy...) on my machine, with Hyperthreading enabled. That means I have 4 threads on a dual-core CPU.
Python only runs one one thread at a time, would disabling Hyperthreading in the BIOS make my program run nearly 2x faster? (only two threads would be available, one per CPU)

Thanks

Comment: just in case it matters, what OS? Why not benchmark it?

Comment: No;  It would not make it faster.  You could disable the other core and it would run at identical speeds because your only using one core in the first place.  Determine the reason your only using one core, it should be possible, for your python code to use all your cores.

Comment: @Ramhound well there is no apparent reason, any 32bit program - as far as I experienced - always use only one thread at a time. Have you ever seen a counterexample?

Comment: I can write a multi-threaded 32-bit application in 200 lines of code, don't know Python, so it would be c#

Comment: @adrienlucca.wordpress.com We were running multithreaded 32-bit programs long before 64-bit even existed for PCs. I've written many such. There is nothing about multithreading that needs 64 bits.